# Handling events exposed on a .NET class via COM in VB6

Tags: .net, com, vb6, interop

Handling events exposed on a .NET class via COM in VB6

My test .NET (class libary registered for interop in compiler settings) code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch), ComVisible(True)> _
Public Interface MyEventInterface
    <DispId(1)> Event Exploded(ByVal Text As String)
    <DispId(2)> Sub PushRedButton()
End Interface


<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
Public Class EventTest
    Implements MyEventInterface

    Public Event Exploded(ByVal Text As String) Implements MyEventInterface.Exploded

    Public Sub PushRedButton() Implements MyEventInterface.PushRedButton

        RaiseEvent Exploded("Bang")

    End Sub

End Class
```

My test VB6 application winforms code (which references the above class libary):

```
Public ct As New ComTest1.EventTest

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    ct.add_Exploded (ExplodedHandler)

    ct.PushRedButton

    ct.remove_Exploded (ExplodedHandler)

End Sub

Private Sub ExplodedHandler(ByVal Text As String)

    MsgBox Text

End Sub
```

Specifially I'm not sure how to set up the handler in VB6 the compile error I get is "Argument not optional" on this line in the VB6:

```
ct.add_Exploded (ExplodedHandler)
```

Comment: Where is your add_Exploded declared?

Comment: The COM attributes created it. i.e. in VB6 intellisense add_ and remove_ are present due to the Idispatch interface I believe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(`the interface name`))>` for the events in .NET and `WithEvents` in VB6

.NET class libary:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

' This interface is to expose the events
<Guid("28C7DCE1-90EF-4a30-AF7F-4187F9FFFDEB")> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
Public Interface MathsEvents
    <DispId(1)> _
    Sub Calculated(ByVal Result As Double)
End Interface

' This interface is to expose the properties and methods
<Guid("86CE5E8D-777D-4cd5-8A7D-7F58737F1DB4")> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
Public Interface _Maths
    <DispId(2)> _
    Property ValueA() As Double
    <DispId(3)> _
    Property ValueB() As Double
    <DispId(4)> _
    ReadOnly Property Result() As Double
    <DispId(5)> _
    Sub Add()
End Interface

' This is the actual class
' The events are exposed by using the ComSourceInterfaces attribute
' The properties and methods are exposed using the Implements keyword
<Guid("C58721B1-15B3-4eeb-9E1E-BCDA33D38EE6")> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
<ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(MathsEvents))> _
Public Class Maths
    Implements _Maths
    Public Event Calculated(ByVal Result As Double)
    Private mValueA As Double
    Private mValueB As Double
    Private mResult As Double

    Public Property ValueA() As Double Implements _Maths.ValueA
        Get
            Return mValueA
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            mValueA = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ValueB() As Double Implements _Maths.ValueB
        Get
            Return mValueB
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            mValueB = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Result() As Double Implements _Maths.Result
        Get
            Return mResult
        End Get

    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        mValueA = 0
        mValueB = 0
        mResult = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add() Implements _Maths.Add
        mResult = mValueA + mValueB
        RaiseEvent Calculated(mResult)
    End Sub

End Class
```

VB6 test application:

```
Private WithEvents calc As Maths

Private Sub btnAdd_Click()

   calc.ValueA = CDbl(txtValueA.Text)
   calc.ValueB = CDbl(txtValueB.Text)
   calc.Add

End Sub

Private Sub calc_Calculated(ByVal Result As Double)
   txtResult.Text = CStr(Result)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

   Set calc = New Maths

End Sub
```

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to do this with just one interface for both the events and the properties / methods ?

Comment: `_Maths` is `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch`, so it shouldn't be available only by late binding? In example is used as early binding - or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

C#

```
[ComVisible(true)] //Exposed
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)] //Our managed interface will be IDispatch
public interface IMathEvents
{

    void OnOperationCompleted(string message);

}
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMathEvents))]  //Our event source is IMathEvents interface
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IMath))]
public class Math:IMath  /*IMath interface just declares a method named Add */
{
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        if (null != this.OnOperationCompleted)
            this.OnOperationCompleted("Operation completed, result: " + (x+y).ToString());
        return x + y;
    }

    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void OperationCompletedDel(string message); //No need to expose this delegate
    public event OperationCompletedDel OnOperationCompleted;

}
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMath
{
    int Add(int x, int y);
}
```

vb

> Private WithEvents m As Math
>
> Private Sub Form_Load()
>
> ```
> Set m = New PayClient.Math
> ```
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub m_OnOperationCompleted(ByVal Text As String)
>
> ```
> MsgBox Text
> ```
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Command2_Click()
>      m.Add 1, 2
>
> End Sub