# How might VB6 prevent COM events being delivered (.net -> VB6 via COM)?

Tags: .net, com, vb6

So I'm writing a component in C# with events that needs to be exposed over COM to VB6.

I've already taken all the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766656/handling-events-exposed-on-a-net-class-via-com-in-vb6), and **the events themselves work fine**.

However, **something** in the machinery of the app means that **sometimes COM events aren't delivered** (when multiple events fire in close succession, only the first gets through). I've got to the stage of tracing data immediately before it's raised as an event on the .net side and immediately after it's handled on the VB side. They are not merely being queued up, or conveyed out of order (would be (more) acceptable), they are raised but not received. All events are raised from the same .net thread. **When I step through the code, they are all delivered correctly; in a bare-bones test app they are all delivered even "at speed".**

So some other part of the VB app appears to be preventing these events being delivered. Where should I start looking? Can DoEvents have unintended side effects, for example?

EDIT: clarified the above that only the first of the batch is getting through.

EDIT: restated case (originally COM wrapper was believed to be the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 6 days of debugging later I arrived at the solution: COM events are just binned and not delivered when you're at a breakpoint in debug mode. What I was seeing was a combination of two things:

1. The main programming loop assumed after the first event it should just continue on and do it's thing; therefore when the other events later arrived, we were no longer calling "DoEvents" to allow them entry to the main thread; and they got delayed to the point they were irrelevant.
2. All my efforts to diagnose the situation came down to, at some point, putting a breakpoint in the code to see what was going on/step through it/ add new code to output variables etc. If I was at a breakpoint when the event was delivered, the event was just binned without being queued up.

Hopefully this can save someone else wasting this much time on such a stupid issue...

Comment: Glad you figured it out! So the solution was to make the main VB programming loop continue to expect more events after the first one?

Comment: essentially - the events are of more than one type, so I just told it to wait until the correct type (rather than waiting for the first one to arrive). The depressing thing was I already realised this was necessary - if I just went ahead and did it before trying to debug the issue, I would've saved a lot of trouble *sobs*

Answer (score 2):

Your VB6 code is most likely running in an apartment so has to run a message pump to accept incoming events. Your .Net object will raise a COM event, this sends a message to the apartment of your VB6 stuff and it handles the message. If the COM subsystem is using SendMessageTimeout then its possible the raised events are being dropped because your VB6 code is too slow to handle them - but normally you get an error complaining that the remote client is inaccessible if something gets tied up.
In general it is a good idea to do the absolute minimum in a COM event handler. This generally means raise your own event or post your own messages to yourself. This is to prevent tying up the remote clients thread. So I would suggest limiting your event handler to just calling RaiseEvent on a new event defined in your VB6 code. Ensure the rest of your VB6 is event oriented and it should work out ok.

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back - but are Vb6 events not synchronous? In which case the remote thread would still be tied up responding to the secondary event?

Comment: No change. The rest of the VB6 is not event-oriented; are there any strategies beyond re-writing it to be event-oriented?

Comment: I modified my code so that only thing the event handler does is log the received message, to ensure it wasn't a timeout issue; no joy. Same problem.