# Subscribe to C# .net Event in VB6

Tags: .net, com, vb6

I need to get be able to handle a .net event in VB6. So far i have it set up by making me c# class COM visible. My VB6 object can call methods on it fine but now i need some way to communicate from .net to VB. If i add an event to my c# class the .net wrapper seems to add an add_EventName and remove_EventName which i assume this is to subscribe and unsubscribe to the event. But i'm still a novice when it comes to VB6 and come so i'm not really sure how to use it.

The add_EventName seems to take an EventNameEventHadler but what do i give it? i tried the sub but this gives me a runtime error. Anyone know how to use this? Here is an example of what i have

```
Private oHost As HostService.IHost

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set oHost = New HostService.Host
    oHost.Start
    oHost.add_EvalReceived EvalReceivedEventHandler
End Sub

Private Sub EvalReceivedEventHandler(ByVal sender As Variant, ByVal e As EvalReceivedEventArgs)
MsgBox "Eval Received in VB: " & e.Eval.TimeSent & ":" & e.Eval.FirstName & " " & e.Eval.LastName & " - " & e.Eval.Comments
End Sub
```

So oHost.add_EvalReceived line is wrong

Comment: oh and the oHost is my COM visible .net object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding `WithEvents` to your declaration of `oHost`

```
Private WithEvents oHost As HostService.IHost
```

Then the IDE should allow you to create event handlers on `oHost`. It's just like making your `Form_Load` event handler. The drop-down at the top-left of the code window should let you select `oHost`.

Disclaimer: I've used this many times to handle events from COM objects. I've never actually tried handling events from a .Net object through interop, but I would think you must do it like this.

Comment: Is there anything else you need to do to the .net Object? I get the message "Object does not source automation events" when i try to compile

Comment: @Nitro52 I don't know, sorry :( I've never actually used this with an interop object. You could check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766656/handling-events-exposed-on-a-net-class-via-com-in-vb6/2772558#2772558)?

Answer (score 4):

Ok i got it working with help from MarkJ. I had to have an interface that represents my events for COM. So they ended up looking like this

```
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IHostEvents))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("037CF765-4C30-4CF7-969C-1775E79844CE")]
public class Host : IHost
{
    //IHost implementation
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("8C0C3F0E-5793-4E11-AB20-3A556C0B6790")]
public interface IHostEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void EvalReceived(object sender, EvalReceivedEventArgs e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB6 you can use the `AddressOf` operator to create the delegate implicitly:

```
oHost.add_EvalReceived AddressOf EvalReceivedEventHandler
```