# Why doesn't .NET interop event handler get hit in VB6 IDE?

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vb6

I have a VB6 application with some .NET controls and .NET interop classes. One thing I've noticed is that the events raised by the .NET classes only get handled as expected in the VB6 code when I run the application from the project's compiled executable file. When I run the application through the VB6 IDE, though, the event handlers don't get hit--the code within them doesn't even execute. (Obviously, breakpoints don't get hit.)

This does not seem to be the case for events raised by interop controls--I can hit breakpoints for these. Only "non-control" classes have this issue.

I followed the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3.aspx) when setting up and calling my .NET Interop class's events.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I checked out some posts here and on MSDN (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075497/subscribe-to-c-sharp-net-event-in-vb6) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766656/handling-events-exposed-on-a-net-class-via-com-in-vb6)), but nothing I've found fixes the issue of these event handlers not getting executed while in debug.

Answer (score 5):

The VB6 IDE is a pretty hostile place for managed code.  It doesn't make any attempt to simulate a process, the kind you have when you run your app from the compiled version.  So any .config file you use doesn't work, the CLR has no hope of finding any dependent assemblies and you're blind as a bat without a managed debugger.  Put a few too many Try/Catch statements in your code and you have no hope of finding out why your code doesn't work.

You'll have to do this differently and use the managed debugger.  You can *still* use the VB6 debugger, its disadvantages are also an advantage, it doesn't get in the way of the managed debugger.

Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Select the "Start external program" radio button and select c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vb98\vb6.exe.  You can set the "Command line arguments" to the path of the .vbp project if you have one.  Press F5 to start the debugger.

That starts the VB6 IDE.  You can set a breakpoint in your .NET code like you normally do.  Whenever a VB6 statement invokes your [ComVisible] code, such a breakpoint will hit so you can debug it.  Use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR Exceptions so you'll always see something going wrong in your .NET code.

Comment: OK, thanks. It sounds from your response as though there's no real hope of being able to hit a break point in one of these handler methods, then. Do you happen to know why it works for event handlers for .NET controls?

Comment: That's completely not what I said.  Please re-read the answer.  And above all, **try it**.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I did try what you described. The VB6 event handler code still isn't being hit while running my app through the VB6 IDE (which I launched through VS, as you described above). I see the same behavior I described in my initial posting.

Comment: So set a breakpoint on the code that fires the event in your .NET code.  Work back from there.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me again and for all of your time on this. I'd already had the breakpoint set in my .net code. It gets hit, but there's no evidence that my VB6 code is getting hit. The functionality in the VB6 event handler is omitted and the VB6 breakpoint doesn't get hit. The code still isn't being hit in debug. I Enabled Debugging of Unmanaged Code in the .NET project in which the event gets raised, but that seemed to have no effect. (I think it was attempting to debug VB6.exe, anyway, since that was the attached process.)